# PHP Include displaying script rather than output

Tags: php, mysql, php-include

I'm fairly new to PHP, but have been able to use include files previously.

I'm trying to include a dynamic league standings table to a page.

The code works fine on the page on its own, but when I try to add it into an include file, it just displays the script. I assume that it's an issue with what you can use in an include, but I'm struggling to work out what the rules of what you can or can't do in an include file are??

Both files are sat in the same directory, and i'm using the  syntax.

The code I'm trying to include is:

```
      $result = mysql_query("
        select team, 
        count(*) played, 
        count(case when HomeScore > AwayScore then 1 end) wins, 
        count(case when AwayScore > HomeScore then 1 end) lost, 
        count(case when HomeScore = AwayScore then 1 end) draws, 
        sum(HomeScore) goalsfor, 
        sum(AwayScore) goalsagainst,
        sum(HomeScore) - sum(AwayScore) goal_diff, 
        sum(case when HomeScore > AwayScore then 3 else 0 end + case 
        when HomeScore = AwayScore then 1 else 0 end) score 
        from (select 
            HomeTeam team, 
            HomeScore, 
            AwayScore 
        from Game 
            union all 
        select  AwayTeam, 
            AwayScore, 
            HomeScore 
        from Game) a 
        group by team 
        order by score desc, 
        goal_diff desc;");

  echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Team</th>
    <th>Win</th>
    <th>Loss</th>
    <th>Tie</th>
    <th>Goals For</th>
    <th>Goals Against</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['team'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['wins'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['lost'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['draws'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['goalsfor'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['goalsagainst'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['score'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
  echo "</table>";
```

Apologies for the formatting, still getting used to spacing!

Thanks guys

Comment: and how you include the file please post the code.

Comment: Are you starting that file with `<?php`? Otherwise, it drops you to raw output mode.

Comment: @Wrikken What a pleb!!! Solved. Thanks guys, haven't needed to do that for my includes previously, but I think has more in it than then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the all of PHP code in  tags.